# Rails cancancan how to limit user privilige in view when there are lots of roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan, rolify

Rails cancancan how to limit user privilige in view when there are lots of roles? And each role has multiple priviliges.
For example, in my rails app there are about 50 view files, such as article.html.erb, product.html.erb, comment.html.erb, order.html.erb,...,and so on. What I have to do is adding priviliges in every .html.erb file:

```
 <% if can? :update, @article %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
 <% end %>
...
 <% if can? :update, @product %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(@product) %>
 <% end %>
```

So if in this way, I have to do a lot of tedious works. When the requestment is changed, I have to modify multiple .html.erb files.

So my question is, if there is any methods that I can accept to avoid this way? Such as using a global tag to control all the views to display or not display the "Edit","Destroy" methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [layouts in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).
Create a partial view, say `_user_privileges.html.erb` inside `layouts` folder in `app/views` and write the code related to privileges there. Now in each of the other view files you can use `<%= render 'layouts/user_privileges'  %>`. So now you can use a single file to change the privileges.

**_user_privileges.html.erb**

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
 <% end %>
...
 <% if can? :update, @product %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(@product) %>
 <% end %>
```

**article.html.erb, product.html.erb, comment.html.erb, order.html.erb etc.**

```
...
<%= render 'layouts/user_privileges'  %>
...
```

Comment: If I create a partial view, I have to change the partial view every time as the development needs change. So my question is, if I could just add a tag in the view or a more easy way such as using a gem to do it? If there is a gem or a more easy method to do this, I will appreciate. @Sajin